# Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered'."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm encountering this error when trying to create a service using Task Definition in my ECS Cluster:

> Encountered error deploying NoteAppService. Resource handler message: "Operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered' encountered an error." (RequestToken: a9b4170a-b382-355d-0dc5-ae55cc25d314, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

Consequently, I'm unable to create the service in the cluster. I have tried multiple times but error still persists.
Lacking experience, I'm unsure about the specific error and how to resolve it.
The following is my *Task Definition* file:

```json
{
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:755204033406:task-definition/NoteappTaskDefin:1",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "Container1",
      "image": "public.ecr.aws/d4a1q9y6/note_app_public_repo",
      "cpu": 0,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "name": "container1-3000-tcp",
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "appProtocol": "http"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "environment": [],
      "environmentFiles": [],
      "mountPoints": [],
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "ulimits": [],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-create-group": "true",
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/NoteappTaskDefin",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        },
        "secretOptions": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "family": "NoteappTaskDefin",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::755204033406:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "revision": 1,
  "volumes": [],
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "cpu": "1024",
  "memory": "3072",
  "runtimePlatform": {
    "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
    "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
  },
  "registeredAt": "2023-08-22T09:37:03.162Z",
  "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::755204033406:root",
  "tags": []
}
```

[image: AWS Console Screenshot]

Comment: That error just means your ECS Task (docker image) is failing to start. You need to look at the logs for the ECS task to determine what the actual issue is. Looking at your task definition, you can find those logs in CloudWatch logs under `/ecs/NoteappTaskDefin`.

Comment: Did anyone got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is commonly attributed to a failure in initiating the container. Please examine the logs for more insights.

Additionally,  consider specifying the `entryPoint` and `command` parameters within the `containerDefinitions` section.

```bash
{
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:755204033406:task-definition/NoteappTaskDefin:1",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "Container1",
      "image": "public.ecr.aws/d4a1q9y6/note_app_public_repo",
      "cpu": 0,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "name": "container1-3000-tcp",
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "appProtocol": "http"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "entryPoint": [
        "sh",
        "-c"
      ],
      "command": [
        "your command here"
      ]
    }
  ]
  
  […]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I believe it can be due to multiple reasons.

If case the obvious troubleshooting does not help try checking CloudTrail logs.

I eventually checked `Cloudtrail` logs and noticed an `AccessDenied error` regarding `logs:CreateLogGroup` for the ECS TaskExecutionRole. I added the missing permission in the role, and it worked great!